# How to search by Dates and Times with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, spring-data-jpa

I'm leaning about Spring Data JPA and I have an app and I try to search by Dates and it doesn't work.

The problem is when I try to search for a Date in the db. I have a MySQL db and if I search directly in the MySQL Workbench is working, but if I try to search from my app is not working. I get nothing. If I try to search for something else I get the results. So I'm sure there is a problem when I try to search for a Date. I have no idea what is the problem. Any feedback will be appreciated. Thank you!

**Update**

At the begining the app worked perfectly. I could search by the date in the db. After that I added Spring Security and some more entities and after that I cannot search by the date in the db, and I didn't touch the search method. And this is very weird. Now I have the first version of app and it works, and the second version doesn't work. And both applications target the same db instance. But the problem is only when I try to search by the date, if I search by the departureCity and arrivalCity it works perfectly, when I try to search by the Date I get nothing, the list is empty.

Here is the version of the app that doesn't work. And here is the Github link -> https://github.com/eveningstar33/flightreservationapp

And here is the other app that works perfectly: https://github.com/eveningstar33/flightreservation

**Entities**:

AbstractEntity class:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Flight class:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Flight extends AbstractEntity {

    private String flightNumber;
    private String operatingAirlines;
    private String departureCity;
    private String arrivalCity;

    private LocalDate dateOfDeparture;
    private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;

    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }

    public void setFlightNumber(String flightNumber) {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }

    public String getOperatingAirlines() {
        return operatingAirlines;
    }

    public void setOperatingAirlines(String operatingAirlines) {
        this.operatingAirlines = operatingAirlines;
    }

    public String getDepartureCity() {
        return departureCity;
    }

    public void setDepartureCity(String departureCity) {
        this.departureCity = departureCity;
    }

    public String getArrivalCity() {
        return arrivalCity;
    }

    public void setArrivalCity(String arrivalCity) {
        this.arrivalCity = arrivalCity;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateOfDeparture() {
        return dateOfDeparture;
    }

    public void setDateOfDeparture(LocalDate dateOfDeparture) {
        this.dateOfDeparture = dateOfDeparture;
    }

    public Timestamp getEstimatedDepartureTime() {
        return estimatedDepartureTime;
    }

    public void setEstimatedDepartureTime(Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime) {
        this.estimatedDepartureTime = estimatedDepartureTime;
    }

}
```

Passenger class:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Passenger extends AbstractEntity {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

}
```

Reservation class:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Reservation extends AbstractEntity {

    private Boolean checkedIn;
    private int numberOfBags;
    @OneToOne
    private Passenger passenger;
    @OneToOne
    private Flight flight;

    public Boolean getCheckedIn() {
        return checkedIn;
    }

    public void setCheckedIn(Boolean checkedIn) {
        this.checkedIn = checkedIn;
    }

    public int getNumberOfBags() {
        return numberOfBags;
    }

    public void setNumberOfBags(int numberOfBags) {
        this.numberOfBags = numberOfBags;
    }

    public Passenger getPassenger() {
        return passenger;
    }

    public void setPassenger(Passenger passenger) {
        this.passenger = passenger;
    }

    public Flight getFlight() {
        return flight;
    }
    public void setFlight(Flight flight) {
        this.flight = flight;
    }

}
```

Role class:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class Role extends AbstractEntity {

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
             CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_role",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
            )
    private Set<User> users;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

User class:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
             CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

FlightController class:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.controllers;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities.Flight;
import com.dgs.flightreservationapp.repos.FlightRepository;

@Controller
public class FlightController {

    @Autowired
    private FlightRepository flightRepository;

    @GetMapping("/findFlights")
    public String findFlights() {

        return "findFlights";
    }

    @PostMapping("processFlights")
    public String processFlights(@RequestParam("from") String from, @RequestParam("to") String to,
            @RequestParam("departureDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy") LocalDate departureDate,
            ModelMap modelMap) {

        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< " + departureDate);

        List<Flight> flights = flightRepository.findByDepartureCityAndArrivalCityAndDateOfDeparture(from, to, departureDate);
        modelMap.addAttribute("flights", flights);
        return "displayFlights";
    }

}
```

UserController class:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/showMyLoginPage")
    public String showMyLoginPage() {

        return "login/fancy-login";

    }

}
```

FlightRepository:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.repos;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities.Flight;

public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Long>  {

//  @Query("from Flight where departureCity=:departureCity and arrivalCity=:arrivalCity and dateOfDeparture=:dateOfDeparture")
//  List<Flight> findFlights(@Param("departureCity") String from, 
//                           @Param("arrivalCity") String to,
//                           @Param("dateOfDeparture") LocalDate departureDate);

    List<Flight> findByDepartureCityAndArrivalCityAndDateOfDeparture(String from, String to, LocalDate departureDate);

}
```

UserRepository:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.repos;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .permitAll();
    }

}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities.User;
import com.dgs.flightreservationapp.repos.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);


        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found for email " + username);
        }

        return new UserPrincipal(user);
    }

}
```

UserPrincipal

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.security;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities.Role;
import com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities.User;

public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public UserPrincipal(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.dgs.flightreservationapp.entities.User;
import com.dgs.flightreservationapp.repos.UserRepository;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("\n\nIn customAuthenticationSuccessHandler\n\n");

        String userName = authentication.getName();

        System.out.println("userName=" + userName);

        User theUser = userRepository.findByUsername(userName);

        // now place in the session
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("user", theUser);

        // forward to home page

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/findFlights");
    }

}
```

MySQL schema:

```
CREATE DATABASE reservation

USE reservation


CREATE TABLE user
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(20),
email VARCHAR(20),
password VARCHAR(256), 
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY (email)
);

CREATE TABLE flight
(
  id INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  flight_number VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL, 
  operating_airlines VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  departure_city VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  arrival_city VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
  date_of_departure DATE  NOT NULL,
  estimated_departure_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
  PRIMARY KEY (id);
)

CREATE TABLE passenger
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(256),
  last_name VARCHAR(256),
  middle_name VARCHAR(256),
  email VARCHAR(50),
  phone VARCHAR(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE reservation
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  checked_in TINYINT(1),
  number_of_bags INT,
  passenger_id INT,
  flight_id INT,
  created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (passenger_id) REFERENCES passenger(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (flight_id) REFERENCES flight(id)
);

CREATE TABLE role
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table user_role(
user_id int,
role_id int,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES user(id),
FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
REFERENCES role(id)
);

insert into flight values(1,'AA1','American Airlines','AUS',
'NYC',STR_TO_DATE('02-05-2018', '%m-%d-%Y'),'2018-02-05 03:14:07');

insert into flight values(2,'AA2','American Airlines','AUS',
'NYC',STR_TO_DATE('02-05-2018', '%m-%d-%Y'),'2018-02-05 05:14:07');

insert into flight values(3,'AA3','American Airlines','AUS',
'NYC',STR_TO_DATE('02-05-2018', '%m-%d-%Y'),'2018-02-05 06:14:07');

insert into flight values(4,'SW1','South West','AUS',
'NYC',STR_TO_DATE('02-05-2018', '%m-%d-%Y'),'2018-02-05 07:14:07');

insert into flight values(5,'UA1','United Airlines','NYC',
'DAL',STR_TO_DATE('02-05-2018', '%m-%d-%Y'),'2018-02-05 10:14:07');

insert into flight values(6,'UA1','United Airlines','NYC',
'DAL',STR_TO_DATE('02-05-2018', '%m-%d-%Y'),'2018-02-05 10:14:07');

insert into flight values(7,'SW1','South West','AUS',
'NYC',STR_TO_DATE('02-06-2018', '%m-%d-%Y'),'2018-02-06 07:14:07');

insert into flight values(8,'SW2','South West','AUS',
'NYC',STR_TO_DATE('02-06-2018', '%m-%d-%Y'),'2018-02-06 08:14:07');


insert into flight values(9,'SW3','South West','NYC',
'DAL',STR_TO_DATE('02-06-2018', '%m-%d-%Y'),'2018-02-06 10:14:07');

insert into flight values(10,'UA1','United Airlines','NYC',
'DAL',STR_TO_DATE('02-06-2018', '%m-%d-%Y'),'2018-02-06 10:14:07');

insert into user values(1,'John','Doe','john@gmail.com',
'$2a$04$eFytJDGtjbThXa80FyOOBuFdK2IwjyWefYkMpiBEFlpBwDH.5PM0K');
```

And you can login with john@gmail.com and password is fun123

If you want to test the other app that works perfectly you need to add this in the db:

```
insert into user values(2,'Tom','Abc','tom@gmail.com','fun123');
```

Then login with tom@gmail.com and fun123, and at Fin Flights put AUS, NYC and 02-05-2018 and you will have results for this app. But for the other app you don't recipe any result. This is very weird.

Comment: Just log the query and check it

Comment: Possibly a time component in the specified Date. As it is Date only with no time component maybe makes more sense to switch type to `java.time.LocalDate`. As noted above however enable SQL logging and see what is being generated.

Comment: Thank you for help. The problem is not the query, I'm using the same query for another app with the same db and it works perfectly. After added Spring Security and more entities it doesn't work. At this moment one app works the other doesn't work. I've added the complete app at my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue happens because of the data conversion

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: select flight0_.id as id1_0_, flight0_.arrival_city as arrival_2_0_, flight0_.date_of_departure as date_of_3_0_, flight0_.departure_city as departur4_0_, flight0_.estimated_departure_time as estimate5_0_, flight0_.flight_number as flight_n6_0_, flight0_.operating_airlines as operatin7_0_ from flight flight0_ where flight0_.departure_city='AUS' and flight0_.arrival_city='NYC' and flight0_.date_of_departure='2018-02-04 18:30:00.0'

As you can see the date is not converted in the correct format, so we push in our own converter to fix the issue.

**flightreservationapp/converters/LocalDateAttributeConverter.java**

```java
package com.dgs.flightreservationapp.converters;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return locDate == null ? null : locDate.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(String sqlDate) {
        return sqlDate == null ? null : LocalDate.parse(sqlDate);
    }
}
```

After adding this file, you will start getting results

[image: Working fine]

You have other options also. Add annotation to your JPA methods

```java
    List<Flight> findByDepartureCityAndArrivalCityAndDateOfDeparture(String from, String to,
                                                                     @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
                                                                     LocalDate departureDate);
```

And then you need to make sure you set your timezone also to be UTC

```java
public class FlightReservationAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FlightReservationAppApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
}
```

Another option is to use the higher version of hibernate in your `pom.xml`

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

and setting the timezone also

```java
public class FlightReservationAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FlightReservationAppApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to annotate the date field in entity with `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)`

like

```
@Entity
public class Flight extends AbstractEntity {

    private String flightNumber;
    private String operatingAirlines;
    private String departureCity;
    private String arrivalCity;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateOfDeparture;

    private Timestamp estimatedDepartureTime;
}
```

Comment: I also did that and nothing, the list is empty

Comment: is the db date format and input format same ? @gaby

Comment: db format is date and input format is date. I have this problem after I added Spring Security, before that it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

MySql `Date` type [does not contain any time part in it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), so the `Date` type you are using on your `Flight` entity, and its time part might be breaking your query. Try replacing `Date` with `LocalDate` from Java8 Date/Time API, which also only contains date without any time information.

```
private LocalDate dateOfDeparture;
```

&

```
@Param("dateOfDeparture") LocalDate departureDate
```

---

On top of that you don't need to use a `@Query` for such a simple logic. You can use [method names as queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) which is a sweet feature of Spring Data JPA.

```
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Long>  {

    List<Flight> findByDepartureCityAndArrivalCityAndDateOfDeparture(String from, String to, LocalDate departureDate);
}
```

and call this from your controller;

```
@PostMapping("/processFlights")
public String processFlights(..) {

    List<Flight> flights = flightRepository.findByDepartureCityAndArrivalCityAndDateOfDeparture(from, to, departureDate);

    modelMap.addAttribute("flights", flights);
    return "displayFlights";
}
```

Though it looks terrible, since the name becomes way too long. You can add a default method to wrap it to hide the ugly naming.

```
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, Long>  {

    List<Flight> findByDepartureCityAndArrivalCityAndDateOfDeparture(String from, String to, LocalDate departureDate);

    // you can use this from your controller
    default List<Flight> findFlights(String from, String to, LocalDate departureDate) {
        return findByDepartureCityAndArrivalCityAndDateOfDeparture(from, to, departureDate);
    }
}
```

Doing so will hide the complexity & probable bugs that is due to using `@Query` annotation & hard-coding JPQL in it unless it is absolutely necessary for more advanced cases.

---

I added the following code in your [`flightreservationapp`](https://github.com/eveningstar33/flightreservationapp);

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FlightReservationAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(FlightReservationAppApplication.class, args);
        FlightRepository flightRepository = run.getBean(FlightRepository.class);

        Flight flight = new Flight();
        flight.setDepartureCity("AUS");
        flight.setArrivalCity("NYC");
        flight.setDateOfDeparture(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 5));
        flightRepository.save(flight);

        List<Flight> list = flightRepository.findByDepartureCityAndArrivalCityAndDateOfDeparture("AUS", "NYC", LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 5));
        System.out.println(list.size());  // prints out 1
    }
}
```

The repository works, I am unable to run other end points etc, but there is no issue with query/schema etc.

Comment: Many  would argue manually defining the query is an improvement on a method named `findByDepartureCityAndArrivalCityAndDateOfDeparture`

Comment: @AlanHay I agree 100%, that is why I gave a solution to that *ugliness* without resorting to `@Query` using a `default` wrapper method.

Comment: Fair enough. The ugly method still exists though!

Comment: Thanks for help but it's not working. I have 2 app, the 1st app is much simpler and it's working I can search by the Date. In the 2nd app I've added some Spring Security and more entities and I'm using @ManyToMany and I cannot search by the Date. The repository is identical with the 1st app and in the 1st app I can search by the Date and in the 2nd app I cannot search by the Date. I really don't know what is the problem.

Comment: @gaby that is weird... Are you sure that both applications target the same db instance? Without more details it is really hard to help you sorry. What differences are there between apps, can you list them & add to your question?

Comment: Hi buræquete, thanks for help. Yes both apps target the same db instance. It is very weird. I just updated my question with complete app. Also I've put the github links for both apps.

Comment: @gaby updated my answer, can you test that also in your local? I don't know again what is your problem, it might be you are inserting & querying with mismatching dates maybe? Can you just use `'2012-01-01'` without `STR_TO_DATE`

Comment: @buræquete I did it and it is the same problem

Comment: @gaby can you get when there is no date in params? Just change endpoint to get with artival & departure strings? It might be some other issue than query issue

Comment: @buræquete Yes I can get if there is no date in params. If I search by arrival and departure I get the results, if I search by the date I get nothing

Answer (score 1):

In your nonworking repository (https://github.com/eveningstar33/flightreservationapp), you have this additional config in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservation?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

The part `serverTimezone=UTC` cause your input date and the date in DB mismatch => Wrong result

There's a known bug that happens if client app and mysql server have different timezone:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93444

So for now, either set both to same timezone or refrain from using Local*** class in Java